# How to see the repository implementation generated by Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, repository, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

When is the implementation for repositories generated by Spring Data? At compile time or runtime? Can I see the implementation repository implementation generated by Spring Data?

Comment: I am afraid, both these comments are totally unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## tl;dr

No, for a very simple reason: there's no code generation going on. The implementation is based on proxies and a method interceptor delegating the call executions to the right places.

## Details

Effectively, a method execution can be backed by 3 types of code:

1. The store specific implementation of `CrudRepository`. Have a look for types named `Simple(Jpa|Mongo|Neo4|…)Repository` (see the JPA specific one [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L64)). They have "real" implementations for all of the methods in `CrudRepository` and `PagingAndSortingRepository`.
2. Query methods are effectively executed by `QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(…)` (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/RepositoryFactorySupport.java#L363)). It's basically a 3-step-process to find the delegation target and invoke it. The actual execution is done in classes named `(Jpa|Mongo|Neo4j…)QueryExecution` (see this one for example).
3. Custom implementation code is called directly, also from `QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor`.

The only thing left is the query derivation, which consists of two major parts: method name parsing and query creation. For the former, have a look at `PartTree`. It takes a method name and a base type and will return you a parsed AST-like structure or throw an exception if it fails to resolve properties or the like.

The latter is implemented in classes named `PartTree(Jpa|Mongo|Neo4j|…)Query` and delegates to additional components for actually creating the store specific query. E.g. for JPA the interesting bits are probably in `JpaQueryCreator.PredicateBuilder.build()` (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryCreator.java#L196)).

Comment: Hi Oliver, could you please explain a bit more on how QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor works and when does delegation and invocation happens?

Comment: @xabhi — You might wanna have a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509882/how-are-spring-data-repositories-actually-implemented/38511337#38511337