# Is it possible to create Spring Data auto-implemented repository without initialize Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have this Spring Data repository. Custom methods are auto-implemented by Spring Data (using reflection, proxies or whatever)

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    //custom methods
}
```

Somewhere, I have this:

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;
```

Now, I'm getting rid of Spring context and stop using Spring based dependency injection. I'm wonder if it's possible to create an instance of `UserRepository` without initialize the Spring context. Like this:

```
UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();
```

Obviously, that does not work. But I'm looking for something similar. According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563252/how-to-see-the-repository-implementation-generated-by-spring-data-mongodb), it's not possible to see the repository's generated code because Spring uses proxies runtime.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: It is possible, but will require tons of initializing code.

Comment: Can I know how to start?

Comment: Why are you stopping using Spring whilst you obviously still want to use it. Instead of `@Autowired` you can use the default `@Inject` or `@Resource` but underneath you still need the Spring container. However if you only want to use Spring Data JPA there is out-of-the-box support for using it in a CDI environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. You need to use `RepositoryFactorySupport` class to create the repository.

In my case, I was using Elasticsearch and `ElasticsearchRepository` from Spring Data, so this works for me:

```
ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory factory = new ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory(jestTemplate);
MyRepo myRepo = factory.getRepository(MyRepo.class);
```